# How to create GitHub Actions for unit testing in .NET projects?

Tags: github, nuget, unit-testing

Could You help me? I use **NUnit** framework to test my .NET project. And I want to run my tests via **GitHub Actions**.

What should be included in the assembly of my project? Maybe there are some standard examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to include anything into your assembly to run your tests using GitHub Actions. Just create workflow file in .github/workflows folder with the following content (assuming that you have .NET Core project):

```yaml
---
name: Tests

on: push

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Unit Testing
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      - run: dotnet test
```

> dotnet is pre-installed on windows machine but is not pre-installed on macos and ubuntu. So, you have to install dotnet by adding an extra step in case you want to run it on one of these machines. You can use [actions/setup-dotnet](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-net-core-sdk) action for this purpose.